# A question about irreducible representations of SO(3) group

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups

I have a perplexity about the representations of the group of 3D rotations $SO(3)$.

I'm reading the following text which is describing the irreducible representations of $SO(3)$ that are associated to so called *Wigner-D Matrices*.

[image]

> *'..any matrix representation $\textbf{D}(g)$ of $SO(3)$ that acts on some vector space $V$..'*

Can the group $SO(3)$ act on a more general vector space $V$ that is not $\mathbb{R}^3$? To me this sounds weird. I would describe a *representation* of $SO(3)$ as a map

$$\rho : SO(3) \rightarrow GL_3(\mathbb{R})$$

So for each fixed $g \in SO(3)$,   $\rho(g):\mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ describes a rotation matrix.

In the document above it is stated that the irreps of $SO(3)$ are indexed by  a $l \ge 0$ such that any *rotation* (a general representation that I've described above) can be decomposed as a direct sum of representations acting on suitable vector spaces of dimension $2l+1$. If we take $l=2$ does it make any sense to consider $\rho(g)^{(5)}:\mathbb{R}^5 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^5$ ?

I mean, the group is about **3D** rotations...  Maybe I'm just pretty confused about it.

Comment: I wrote an answer to the more general question 'can a matrix group act on a vector space other than the one on which it is defined' that might be of interest to you (because your question is a special case of that), but it does not contain examples specific to $SO(3)$. Still I recommend it, see here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3902383/101420

Comment: *"Can the group $SO(3)$ act on a more general vector space $V$ that is not $\mathbb R^3$?"* And there you just invented [Representation Theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory), or in particular [Group Representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_representation). You'll be surprised, overwhelmed, and maybe ultimately pleased to see on *how many* vector spaces groups like that can act, and in *how many* ways; and how much knowledge one can get out of that.

Comment: Actually, as a follow-up to my previous comment: Reading those WP articles' intros, the baseline seems to be "it's so cool to study abstract groups by representing them as matrices because everyone understands matrices", to which in our case you could, and maybe should, object: "but my group $SO(3)$ is not "abstract", I literally *define* it as a group of matrices, or endomorphisms of $\mathbb R^3$. So why would I want to represent it as bigger matrices, or endomorphisms on some other vector spaces $V$?". To which I recommend most answers to https://mathoverflow.net/q/153740/27465

Answer (score 3):

Yes, $SO(3,\Bbb R)$ is the naturally seen as the group of all (linear) rotations of $\Bbb R^3$. However, it acts on other spaces (I mean, other than $\Bbb R^3$). For instance, it acts on the space $\Bbb R^{3\times3}$ of all real $3\times3$ matrices this way: if $M\in SO(3,\Bbb R)$ and $A\in\Bbb R^{3\times3}$, then$$M.A=MAM^{-1}.$$But $\Bbb R^{3\times3}$ is a $9$-dimensional vector space.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.. So If I consider action of $SO(3)$ on 3D objects, than I should only consider $l=0,1$ and *truncate* the other subrepresentations? From my undestanding this basically means that I will somehow rotate *separately* $1$-dimensional **parts* (with $D^{(0)}:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$) and $3$-dimensional *parts* (with $D^{(1)}:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$

Comment: Yes, then the sense that any action of $SO(3,\Bbb R)$ on $\Bbb R^3$ either is (up to isomorphism) the standard action of $SO(3,\Bbb R)$ on that space (through rotations), or it is the direct sum of three $1$-dimensional representations.

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to explore José's answer in the context of the passage of the text book.  In other words, believing the textbook, what does it say about José's example?

I'll write $V$ as a short hand for the collection of $3\times 3$ matrices.  As José noted, this this is a $9$-dimensional vector space on which $SO(3)$ acts, so it really comes from a map $SO(3)\rightarrow Gl(V)\cong Gl_9(\mathbb{R})$.

Now, the first thing to note is that conjugation by things in $SO(3)$ fixes the identity $I\in V$ (because conjugation by *any* invertible matrix does).  Moreover, conjugation fixes all real multiples of the identity.

This means that $V$ has a decomposition as $V\cong V_0 \times V'$ where $V'$ is some $8$-dimensional representation of $SO(3)$ and where $V_0 = \operatorname{span}\{I\}$.  By the way, this must be the $V_0$ of your text because a one-dimensional vector space has no non-trivial decomposition at all.

But we can actually identify $V'$. To do so, consider the trace of a matrix.  Note that if $A\in V$ and $B\in SO(3)$, then $tr(BAB^{-1}) = tr(A)$.  Thus, the $SO(3)$ action also preserves the subspace of $V$ consisting of matrices with trace $0$.  Since $V_0$ only intersects this subspace at the $0$-matrix, we may thus identify $V'$ with the traceless $3\times 3$ matrices.

Since $\dim V' = 8$ is even, it must further decompose.  The key to this decomposition is the fact that conjugating by $SO(3)$ preserves symmetric and antisymmetric matrices separately.  That is, if $A\in V$ with $A^t = \lambda A$ with $\lambda \in \{\pm 1\}$, then for any $B\in SO(3)$, we have $$(BAB^{-1})^t = (BAB^t)^t = BA^t B^t = B\lambda A B^t = \lambda BAB^{-1}.$$

Now, the antisymmetric matrices form a subspace $V_1$ of $V'$ of dimension $2(1)+1 = 3$, while the symmetric matrices form a subspace $V_2$ of $V'$ of dimension $2(2) + 1 = 5$.  Since the only matrix which is both symmetric and antisymmetric is the $0$ matrix, we have a decomposition $V'\cong V_1\oplus V_2$.

I claim that both $V_1$ and $V_2$ are irreducible, so that, in particular, the $V_1$ and $V_2$ in the book you are reading.

The proof that $V_1$ is irreducible is easy.  Based on the text you're reading, it if decomposed, it would have to be decompose as a sum of $3$ copies of $V_0$.  Since the action of $SO(3)$ on $V_0$ is trivial, it would then follow that the action of $SO(3)$ on $V_1$ is trivial.  But it's easy to verify that this is not the case.  For example, taking $B = \operatorname{diag}(-1,-1,1)\in SO(3)$ and $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 1\\ 0 & 0 & 0\\ -1 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$, then $BAB^{-1} = -A\neq A$.

For $V_2$, we have to work a bit harder to show that it is irreducible.  If it is irreducible, then by your text, it decomposes either as a sum of 5 copies of $V_0$ or as $V_1\oplus V_0\oplus V_0$.  To show that neither of these occur, it's enough to show that there is no copy of $V_0$ in $V_2$.  That is, that there is no subspace of $V_2$ which is fixed by everything in $SO(3)$.

A general element of $V_5$ looks like $\begin{bmatrix} a & b & c\\ b & d & e \\ c & e & f\end{bmatrix}$ with $a+b+f = 0$.  Conjugating by the three diagonal matrices in $SO(3)$ quickly shows that the only way such an element can be fixed by $SO(3)$ is if it is diagonal.  Now, conjugating by $\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0\\ 1 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}\in SO(3)$ now shows that $a=d$.  Similarly, one finds that $d =f$.  Since $a=b=f$ and $a+b+f = 0$, we have now shown that the only vector in $V_2$ which is fixed by all of $SO(3)$ is the $0$-matrix.

Thus, $V_2$ cannot contain a copy of $V_0$, so it must be irreducible.

In summary, José's example decomposes as $V\cong V_0 \oplus V_1\oplus V_2$.

Comment: Many thanks! I'm going through your answer step by step.. first question: ok conjugation fixes identity, but from this how can we automatically conclude that $V \cong V_0 \times V'$ where $V_0=span\{I\}$ ?

Comment: @James:  Because conjugation fixes the identity, it fixes all multiples of the identity, so it fixes $V_0$.  To get $V'$ we have to do some work.  **IF** the conjugation action preserves *some* inner product $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ in the sense that $\langle BAB^{-1}, BA'B^{-1}\rangle = \langle A,A'\rangle $ for all $A,A'\in V$ and $B\in SO(3)$, then we can define $V'$ as the orthogonal complement to $V_0$.  For $A\in V'$, we have $0 = \langle A, I\rangle = \langle BAB^{-1}, BIB^{-1}\rangle = \langle BAB^{-1}, I\rangle$, so $BAB^{-1}\in V'$ as well.  (continued)

Comment: (More generally, given any representation of any group $G$, if there is an inner product preserved by this action, then the representation splits as a direct sum of irreducible ones).  In the case in my post, we can just write down $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$:  simply define $\langle A, A'\rangle = Trace(AA')$.  But, more generally, if $G$ is compact (and $SO(3)$ is), then you can always find $\langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle$ by averaging any random inner product on $V$.  Lastly, let me just mention that complementary representations do *not* have to exist if there is no invariant inner product.

Answer (score 1):

To get an understanding of the higher-dimensional representations, think of the $SO(3)$ action as a rotation of functions instead of a rotation of vectors. This is how we get higher-dimensional representations, since one can have a large number of linearly independent functions.

For the irreducible representations of $SO(3)$ of dimension $2l+1$, the basis functions are the spherical harmonics with parameters $l, m$, where $m=-l,...,l$.

To get a concrete picture, someone visualised this action for $l$ up to 12 [here](https://vinequai.com/sphericalharmonics-viz2)